# How to display a ROW of data from phpMyAdmin on iOS UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to display a whole row of data on a UITableViewController RATHER than displaying a whole column of data on a UITableViewController.

Here is the kind of code I have which displays the COLUMN of data on a tableview

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Location *object;
    object = [locationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = object.name;
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = object.address;
    cell.publisherLabel.text = object.latitude;
    return cell;
}
```

`name` holds the `Name` column on my database

`address` holds the `Address` column on my database

`latitude` holds the `Latitude` column on my database

below is my database table using phpmyadmin
[image]

> And by doing this, my tableview will look like this

[image]

> I want my tableview to display this

[image]

I'm not sure how to do this at all. Any help will be appreciated please, thank you!

Comment: there can be multiple ways of doing this 
1) multiple your number of records by 3. That would be your total number of rows. so if there are 5 records, 5x3=15 rows. then in cellforrowatindexpath
row 0 - name[0]
row 1 - Address[0]
row 2 - latitude[0]
row 3 - name[1]....

2) take number of records as number of sections. and in each section take 3 rows.  then in cellforrowatindexpath
row 0 section 0 - name[0]
row 1 section 0 - Address[0]
row 2 section 0 - latitude[0]
row 0 section 1 - name[1]....

Comment: @Ashishail Hey thank you for commenting, but it's either that the logic doesnt make sense or that I'm really stupid. Can you elaborate please? I feel like you're on to something

Comment: @Ashishail How about if I were to collect that row into an array of strings and display that array into the tableview...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry the formatting didn't work, see below
The two ways of doing it.
1) multiple your number of records by 3. That would be your total number of rows. so if there are 5 records, 5x3=15 rows. then in `cellforrowatindexpath`

```
row 0 - name[0],  
row 1 - Address[0],  
row 2 - latitude[0],  
row 3 - name[1]....
```

2) take number of records as number of sections. and in each section take 3 rows. then in `cellforrowatindexpath`

```
row 0 section 0 - name[0],  
row 1 section 0 - Address[0],  
row 2 section 0 - latitude[0],  
row 0 section 1 - name[1]....
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to comment, but not enough reputation...

**So first:**

```
UITableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusable....
```

Why don't you assign your dequeue to an UITableViewCell?

**Then second:**
You'll need to define your own UITableViewCell (maybe in your UIStoryboard) and create the classes with it, so you can define all the UILabels you'll need on your cell.

In case you did that already, then dequeue your UITableViewCell as what it is, not as UITableView.

**And third:**
Make sure your objects are set correctly, else obviously you won't get the right fields

**Edit**

If you want all fields in separate cells, then you should only use the textLabel attribute of a cell.

You could work with a modulo operation, having a section for each object and deciding on the modulo of the row which attribute is in this cell.

Comment: Hey, thank you for commenting but this does not answer my question unfortunately. And yea I meant to put UITableViewCell instead of UITableView. And I did do all of that, I have the code that implies that I already have that there.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't get your question then correctly. I will update my answer in a second. But I like Ashishail's answer already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking back at this a few months later and after gaining more experience in iOS development, I think I found the solution to my problem.

I think if I were to put all the information I want under `Apple` or `google` and such then put it in a dictionary and append it to an array.

I have not yet tried this but after doing some Firebase dev, that's what I've been doing and I think it would be the same for this.